# how to make encoded values for cookies? (python)

Tags: security, google-app-engine, session-cookies, python-2.7

I started using python to make an app with google app engine, right now i am using cookies to keep the sessions of each user in the site my current code for generating cookies is the following:

```
expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=90) # expires in 30 days
Cookie1 = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
Cookie1["username"] = username
Cookie1["username"]['expires'] = expires.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
Cookie2 = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
Cookie2["password"] = password
Cookie2["password"]['expires'] = expires.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", Cookie1.output(header=''))
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", Cookie2.output(header=''))
```

The problem is that this way anyone can see the password and username values of those cookies, is there a way to encode those values so that only i know what those cookies are?

Comment: You should do it the way it's usually done, only set a unique token as a cookie for identification and manage the associated session information on the server side.

Comment: thanks, i thought that i should do something like that 
sorry if my question is gonna be stupid but i am kinda new at dealing with cookies, how should i set unique tokens ? 
should i generate total random id the moment a user starts a session and then assign new id for different sessions of the user ?
 is there some other more "proffetional" way to deal with this issue?

Comment: That'd be the manual way, however you shouldn't forget to delete old sessions from your storage. But I bet that libraries exist that handle this for you. At least every web framework I know does it, like Django, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use one of the existing implementations of secure cookies/sessions.
You can use [webapp2 sessions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html).

In my applications I use [Werkzeug secure cookies](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/securecookie/#module-werkzeug.contrib.securecookie) to implement user sessions.

Comment: thx this was helpfull but for now i decided to encode the password at server side then save them in database, every time a user logs in i first encode their passwords and then compare the encoded password provided from the user with the encoded password in the database and that encoded value is saved in each cookie